# no tracking node in blender

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

I want to do single point tracking. For this to work I need to import the X and Y position of the tracked point. This should be done by the "track position" node, but it seems the current version of blender (2.77a) is missing this node.

It gets mentioned in the blender [manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/compositing/types/input/track_position.html) (although there is no description),  but it's missing in my application.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure where you have tried to find it, but it is a compositing node. [image]

And if not familiar with compositing i found this one for single point tracking:
http://cgi.tutsplus.com/tutorials/single-point-tracking-in-blender--cms-24286